SSMS 20 - Query Store - Configure tracked queries broken?
Tracking a query in the Query Store is stuck in SSMS 20 on Avg duration via the Configure option.
It shows a red line around it, but it ignores the selected Metric and Statistic
Any way to solve it?
Running: SQL Server Management Studio   20.0.70.0


You only have one data point. Why do you care about getting the total?

its just an example screenshot to give some visualization of the bug

Its a known issue at Microsoft and will be solved in a later version.
For now if you use it either run scripts or use SSMS 19x.
